# Can't Add Reference to xcdatamodelId

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, xcdatamodel

I have an xcdatamodel file in a static library. To reference the file in my main app, I dragged the file into the main app through xcode.  This worked great.  I added a version to the xcdatamodel file.  This created an xcdatamodelid file.  If I try to drag the xcdatamodelid to my main project, xcode crashes.  I can't drag the xcdatamodel files anymore.
How can I add a reference to my data model?

I'm using xcode 4.6.3.

The top of the xcode stack trace:
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4H1503
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFoundation/DVTFoundation-2091/Framework/Classes/FilePaths/DVTFilePath.m:461
Details:  str should be an instance inheriting from NSString, but it is nil
Object:   <DVTFilePath>
Method:   +filePathForPathString:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x40030a220>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000106670a2a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010591f4e4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001058a1c9f +[DVTFilePath filePathForPathString:] (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x0000000109a5b8d5 -[XCVersionGroup saveCurrentVersion] (in DevToolsCore)
  4  0x0000000109935b53 -[PBXGroup insertItems:atIndex:] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x0000000109ab2b83 -[Xcode3Group insertGroupSubitems:atIndexes:] (in DevToolsCore)
```

Comment: I upgraded to xcode 5 and I it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to xcode 5 and I it works fine now.  As an aside, when I dragged the file to my project, the window didn't give me the option to copy or add reference.  I think this is was a bug with xcode 4.  Now that xcode 5 is out, this is no longer relevant.